# Using a class in PostBack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am totally new to classes and OOP, so please bear with me.

I am creating a large scale web app which I'm trying to keep tidy by creating my own classes.

For instance I have a `Public Class Product` which has several properties. One way I am using it is on page load a product ID is assigned to the ID property which in turn gets the details for that product and assigns the various data to the other properties. So within my code I can used for example product.price or product.description and get the appropriate values. This has worked fine, but I found that because the class was initiated on page load it was getting the data from the DB each time that the page refreshed. I stopped this by using an `If Not IsPostback` to initiate the class. This meant that the data was pulled in only on the initial page load. So far so good.

I then needed to compare a value in a textbox with a property of the product. I have a textchanged event with

`If textbox1.Text <> product.description Then....`

but here I get a wavy line under `product.description` and VS2010 is saying that the object is not defined. Its Dim'd in the page.load so I moved the Dim statement outside the page class so that it will be accessible to all events on the page.

The dim statement is `Dim product as New product`

In my not ispostback chunk of code I have for example `product.ID = 1` which will get all the product properties for product 1

The wavy line has gone but when I run the page all works fine on page load. Data is displayed so my product class is working fine. As soon as I make a change in textbox1 and the event triggers `product.description` is nothing. It got reinitalised.

How do I stop this from happening...

Comment: Please post relevant code blocks. It will be far easier for us to help you if we can see it rather than us trying to visualize it based on your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Product" is not persisted between postbacks.

Only control objects in aspx page are persisted/restored automatically.

To remedy this there are multiple approaches.

If Product is loaded via setting "Product.id=1" then what I woudl do is have a hiddenfield that receives the value of the product.id during prerender event (to save it in the page) and in an init event I would restore the "Product.id=hiddenfield.value" but only when it is a postback to reload your object.

**EDIT**

Thanks for picking my answer. I'll elaborate a little on the various ways to deal with this and why I suggested my answer.

**Store Key in HiddenField Reload from DB**:

PROS: Product is always Fresh/Correct/Current values. Corresponding to the database. Databases are very efficient to return a record based on a primary key. Very little data is sent to and posted back from the client browser. Low complexity. Each page opened by the client is safely isolated.

CONS: Multiple database transactions. If the DB is already strained or extremely massive you may need to consider even the smallest efficiency gain, but this is not common or likely on a primary key based record

**Session State (store entire object)**:

PROS: Lowest time to "load" object since it's available in memory already once loaded. Less DB Transactions. No data piggy backed to the client and back again.

CONS: Object can become "out-of-date" if altered in the DB. Users who open multiple pages of your application can end up getting the wrong object if both require a different "Product", so instead to be totally safe you need a more complex structure in place to store more then one product or store them based on some kind of key (such as the product ID). Server Memory is used, if serving thousands of users or your product data is large it can become an issue, especially if you do this in many pages with many objects.

**Serialization (store the entire object in the page in a field, similar to event state)**:

PROS: Once loaded, the Database is accessed only once for a specific product, then the product is held, in it's entirety inside the page, it is recreated by the server from the data in the field or via viewstate. Each page opened by the client is safely isolated. Is fairly easy to implement storing in ViewState of the Page.

CONS: Object can become "out-of-date" if altered in the DB. ALLOT more data is added to your page responce and the users next page request. Is more complex to implement because the object needs to be designed to be serialized correctly. Complex objects require allot of manual code to be serialized successfully.

again, there are many other ways to deal with this, such as storing items in a synclocked dictionary style object global to the application, but is considerablby more and more complex as you go.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the standard [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) problem.

After you initialize the page, it gets sent to the user's browser.  When the user clicks on something, the browser sends a postback request back to your application.  The view state allows the textbox1 object to remember what was in its Text property.  However, your Page_Load ran from scratch, and, yes, everything including your product object got recreated from scratch.

If you want your product object to "remember" what it knew before the postback, you'll have to remind it.  One way would be to store the initialized value in [Session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and then refresh your product object during the postback section of the Page_Load method.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do a postback, you're working with a **new instance** of your page class. The prior copy of your class was thrown away and probably disposed before your browser even rendered the page to the screen.

If you want to persist a value across http requests (of which postbacks are just one type), then you need to put it somewhere like the Session.

Comment: Many thanks for all your replies... the page can have a fair number of postbacks and initially each time the product class was getting data from the db. I was hoping to eliminate this. I will look at session state and also moving some of the code I have server side to client side so that the number of postbacks are reduced. I can only mark one question as right although you all have answered my question so all please give yourselves a pat on the back. Thanks